# Hide a Floating Action Button of another Layout

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button, nestedscrollview

I have a `FloatingActionButton` inside of may `activity_main.xml` layout which is named `fabBtn`.

My application is built with a `ViewPager` and three `Fragment`s.I want to hide the `FloatingActionButton` when my first `Fragment` detects a scroll, but I keep getting a `NullPointerException` if the user starts scrolling.

I believe it could be that my fragment can't get the `FloatingActionButton` from the `activity_main.xml` layout?

Here is my `activity_main.xml`

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="lh.com.newme.MainActivity"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabBtn"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/codelab_fab_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/codelab_fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_type="normal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_ripple_color"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my first `Fragment` from where I want to hide the `FloatingActionButton`:

```
    public class Ernaehrung extends Fragment {

NestedScrollView nsv;
FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ernaehrung, container, false);
    Button Fruehstuck = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fruehstuck);
    Button Mittagessen = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mittagessen);
    Button Snacks = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.snacks);

    Fruehstuck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent FruehstuckScreen = new Intent(getActivity(), lh.com.newme.Fruehstuck.class);
            startActivity(FruehstuckScreen);
        }
    });

    Mittagessen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent MittagScreen = new Intent(getActivity(), lh.com.newme.Mittagessen.class);
            startActivity(MittagScreen);
        }
    });

    Snacks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent SnackScreen = new Intent(getActivity(), lh.com.newme.Snacks.class);
            startActivity(SnackScreen);
        }
    });

    nsv = (NestedScrollView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Nsv);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabBtn);
    nsv.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (oldScrollY < scrollY){

                fab.hide();
            }

        else
                fab.show();}


    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu_ernaehrung, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.benutzer){

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is my `MainActivity.class` :

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


FloatingActionButton fabBtn;
CoordinatorLayout rootLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tabLayout;

   ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabBtn);



    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fab.show();
                    ...
                    break;

                case 1:
                    fab.show();
                    ...
                    break;


                case 2:
                    fab.hide();
                    break;

                default:
                    fab.hide();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    initInstances();
}

private void initInstances() {

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    rootLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
    fabBtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabBtn);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu_edit, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.einstellungen) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**First of all, change your line**

```
final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabBtn);
```

to

```
fabBtn = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabBtn);
```

---

**Solution #1 - get view (if you need object)**

Then, in your `MainActivity` add getter for your `FloatingActionButton`, like

```
public FloatingActionButton getFloatingActionButton {
    return fabBtn;
}
```

Finally, in your `Fragment` call:

```
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getFloatingActionButton();
```

and

```
if (floatingActionButton != null) {
    floatingActionButton.hide();
}
```

or

```
if (floatingActionButton != null) {
    floatingActionButton.show();
}
```

---

**Solution #2 - add two methods in `MainActivity` (if you need only specific methods, like `show()` / `hide()`)**

```
public void showFloatingActionButton() {
     fabBtn.show();
};

public void hideFloatingActionButton() {
     fabBtn.hide();
};
```

And in your `Fragment` call to hide:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).hideFloatingActionButton();
```

or to show:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).showFloatingActionButton();
```

---

**Note**

If you use more than one `Activity`, you must check if it's proper `Activity`:

```
if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
    getActivity().yourMethod(); // your method here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment your rootView layout is not main layout and you cannot expect the rootView will return the fab button. Thats why you are getting null pointer exception

You better use interface to detect page scrolling and controll it via your activity